# Getting Empty URL value in Google Play Install Referrer API

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am using  Google Play Install Referrer API. But I getting utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic this value.

**Test Url** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfin.partner&referrer=AU000288.

My app right now beta version in play store.

**Using Lib**  Google Play Install Referrer API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

**Testing Url**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.test.test_project&referrer=utm_source%3Dtest_source%26utm_medium%3Dtest_medium%26utm_term%3Dtest-term%26utm_content%3Dtest_content%26utm_campaign%3Dtest_name

**Step 2**
Click on the above link. Open Play store **(Don't Install from play Store)**

**Step 3**
Install from **Android studio.**
You get the result.
Now if you check another Link you need to follow the above step the same manner bcz,

**Note:**
Caution: The install referrer information will be available for **90 days and won't change unless the application is reinstalled.** To avoid unnecessary API calls in your app, you should invoke the API only once during the first execution after install.
[(From Here)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)

**Note:** My App right now Alpha Version(In Play Store)